# Matlab: Matrix with variable number of of columns

Tags: matrices, matlab

in Matlab, I want to define a Matrix A showing portfolio weights over a number of time periods N. Each period has one column in the matrix, so it needs to have N columns, and I need to code this elegantly. So what I want is, for example if N=3:

```
A=[w(1),w(2),w(3)]
```

The vectors w(j) will already have been defined. I tried something like

```
A=@(N)([w(1):w(N)])
```

But it didn't work, and I have no idea how to reach it.

Comment: If each `w(j)` is a vector, how are they being stored? As a cell array? Your idea didn't work because the `:` notation requires scalar inputs.

Comment: >> w(1)

    > In quadprog at 372
      In @(i)(quadprog(QQ(i),-r(i),[],[],ones(1,6),    [1],zeros(6,1),ones(6,1))) 
Optimization terminated.

ans =

    0.0000
    0.0000
         0
         0
   -0.0000
    1.0000

This is what one of the vectors looks like; does that help? else, I don't know what you mean. (the numbers are vertically aligned, but I cannot seem to show that here.)

Comment: oh, and w(i) is stored as a function; they are not stored manually.

Comment: If each $w(i)$ is stores as a function, there is no way to build $A$ without a loop. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each $w(i)$ is stored as a function, there is no *elegant* way to build your matrix $A$ without a for loop.

```
Given: N
       M - number of elements in each w(j)
A = zeros(M,N);

for i =1:N
    A(:,i) = w(i);
end
```

Comment: okay, that is great. But now, w depends on two variables, w(i,j), and if I change j, then A is not going to be redefined. What would I have to write to have this matrix A as a function of i and j? i.e. something like

 A=@(T,j)(for i=1:T
A(:,i)=w(i,j);
end)

Comment: @MarieP I think that will work. You need a comma after $i=1:T$, as this would usually be a new line. It will be slower though since you don't pre allocate $A$.